# Does Azure support payload request/response mappings into documentDB like AWS velocity templates?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

Context: We have a serverless arch on AWS that we're trying to replicate in Azure. We originally used lambda to read/write to dynamo but switched to velocity templates because they're faster.

Goal: Read/Write to Azure's documentDB with a serverless arch.

Potential Solutions:

1. Read/Write with Azure Functions - I've already done this, but suspect it will be too slow once we integrate with front-end
2. Map payload requests/responses with the Azure equivalent of AWS's Velocity Templates

Question: Does Azure support payload request/response mappings into documentDB like AWS velocity templates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can front-end/onboard DocumentDB (now [CosmosDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/introduction)) API's onto [Azure API Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-key-concepts) (which is the API Gateway PAAS service available in Azure) and use the end-points from APIM in Azure functions. You can use [policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-policies) and [liquid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-transformation-policies) templating language to further customize/transform the message or read part of message.